# Android SDK equivalent method for MPL PayPalPayment.setPaymentType()?

Tags: android, paypal, sdk

In the PayPal Mobile Payments Library, we can set the payment type with the `PayPalPayment.setPaymentType()` method. Is there a way to do this with the PayPal Android SDK or iOS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Jeff from PayPal at your service.  No, modifying payment types is not yet supported. However, please keep an eye out, as we plan to support this sometime in the not too distant future! Your best bet is to continue using MPL until it become available.